Moving emails to Deleted Items using Microsoft Graph API
I would like to delete emails in the mailbox of a specific account using C# .NET Microsoft Graph API.
I have seen posts suggesting the DeleteAsync() method, but this permanently deletes the item. Is there a way to delete the email so that it will be moved to the Deleted Items folder instead of being completely unrecoverable?
foreach (Microsoft.Graph.Message currMessage in emails)
{
    string msgId = currMessage.Id;
    string sender = currMessage.From.EmailAddress.Address.ToString();
    string subejct = currMessage.Subject;
    string receivedDate = currMessage.ReceivedDateTime.Value.ToLocalTime().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt");

    await graphClient.Users[emailUser]
        .Messages[msgId]
        .Request()
        .DeleteAsync();
}


Do you use SDK v4 or v5?

Instead of the DeleteAsync method, you need to use the MoveAsync method, where the id of the folder you want to move to is passed. That is, it will roughly look like this: await graphClient.Users[emailUser].Messages[msgId].Request().MoveAsync(folderId);

var requestBody = new MovePostRequestBody { DestinationId = "deleteditems", };  var result = await graphClient.Users[emailUser].Messages["{message-id}"].Move.PostAsync(requestBody); try this

In SDK v5, you can move message to deleted items this way:
using Microsoft.Graph.Me.Messages.Item.Move;

var requestBody = new MovePostRequestBody
{
    DestinationId = "deletedItems",
};

var result = await graphClient.Users[emailUser].Messages["{message-id}"].Move.PostAsync(requestBody);

For SDK v4, it's a little bit different:
var result = await graphClient.Users[emailUser].Messages["{message-id}"].Move("deletedItems").Request().PostAsync();


I'm using v4 and this works perfectly thank you

@NootNootNoob, Come on? Why did you take the answer from the comments? hahaha... In general, I am more and more surprised, the resource is brilliant....
